# Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused. The above error occurred in the <CChart> component

Tags: chart.js, core-ui

When i use CoreUI ChartBar,

```
            data={{
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'GitHub Commits',
                        data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40],
                    },
                ],
            }} type={'bar'} />
```

I am getting an error.
**
chart.esm.js:5354

```
   Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.
at new Chart (chart.esm.js:5354:1)
at renderChart (CChart.tsx:160:1)
at CChart.tsx:242:1
at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23049:1)
at invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25044:1)
at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27304:1)
at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27283:1)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27007:1)
at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26886:1)
```

**

There are no changes to the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `core-ui` is using `react-chartjs-2` under the hood. It's a known issue, but I'm having trouble reproducing the error. Please check out this thread in [react-chartjs-2' issues](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/1037). Specifically [MartinP-C's comment](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/1037#issuecomment-1122236012).

If you could provide a reproduction that would be greatly appreciated.

> I was getting this error (again with React 18.0.1, in Strict Mode)
> Removing Strict Mode stops the error (because Strict Mode double-invokes lifecycle functions when in dev mode? Hence re-use of canvas? https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> However! Strict Mode wasn't the problem itself.
> I had not registered a Chart.JS component and the error being thrown ('"arc" is not a registered element') must have caused React to double-invoke and try to re-use the canvas.

> Fixing the registered element error also stopped "Canvas already in use" error.
> (Registering components: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/migration-to-v4#tree-shaking)

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidmount() {
  <---rest code-->
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: datas,
    options: options,
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.destroyChart();
}

destroyChart() {
  if (this.myChart) {
    this.myChart.destroy();
    // Destroy the chart when the component unmounts
  }
}
```

You can use `useEffect` also.

Comment: you have to use destroy method in chart.js